# c# SQLCOMMAND giving error

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Sqlcommand cmd=new Sqlcommand();
cmd.commandtext="select username, password from \"user\" where username = 'admin' 
 and password = 'password123' ";
adp.fill(ds);
```

Now above query is getting succesffuly executed in mysql and mssql,but my C# code is giving error incorrect sytax "user" 
Where I am wrong?
NOTE:-I want above query to run in mysql and mssql both,and also note that user is reserved keyword in sql

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL use

```
from `user`
```

For SQL Server use

```
from [user]
```

For Oracle use

```
from "user"
```

Comment: But I dont want to write 3 statements I want common C# code to run this query

Comment: I don't think this is going to happen.

Comment: If you want to keep it generic why not just remove the quotes: FROM user

Comment: @DaveSexton: That does not work for SQL Server. Only for MySQL as far as I know.